# SQLPlus DBMS output not the same as in developer

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sql-loader

I'm writing a script that will generate SQLLoader file based on table name. So far, I've managed to do so, but when I run the sql script in SQLPlus I'm not getting the same output as in developer. To be precise, there are new lines inserted when they're not invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Following code is just the beginning without rest of the code. When columns are included I get really messy output with multiple newlines here and there.

Note: I need it to run through SQLPlus as I intend to incorporate the code in Shell script.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    lv_ctl VARCHAR2(32767);
    lv_tableName VARCHAR2(10) := 'MyTable';
BEGIN
    lv_ctl :=  'OPTIONS(SKIP=1)' || CHR(10)
            || 'LOAD DATA' || CHR(10)
            || 'APPEND' || CHR(10)
            || 'INTO TABLE ' || lv_tableName || CHR(10)
            || 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","' || CHR(10)
            || 'TRAILING NULLCOLS' || CHR(10)
            || '(' || CHR(10)
            ;   
    
    dbms_output.put_line(lv_ctl);
END;
/
SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
```

When run through **developer** I get (which is the output I want):

```
OPTIONS(SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
```

When run through **SQLPlus**:

```
OPTIONS(SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE MyTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY
","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
```

The problem is I get new lines randomly, can't find the reason behind it. As you see fifth line (FIELDS TERMINATED BY ",") is not inline.

Comment: If both scripts give you the same result, does it matter that they're not exactly the same?

Comment: Is it possible that the line is wrapping in sqlplus? What happens if you "SET LINESIZE 100" before running your script?

Comment: @pmdba it worked. Please put that as an answer and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure SQLPlus isn't wrapping the output. Try "SET LINESIZE 100" before running your script.

Answer (score 3):

SQL*Plus doesn't play nicely with `dbms_output` when it has newline characters within the string. Those are ignored, for some reason, when SQL*Plus does its own line wrapping. You might be able to `set linesize` to a very large number to avoid this - depending on how big the control file will actually be.

```
set linesize 4000
```

You don't really need to include the line breaks though, you can just output the file one line at a time:

```
DECLARE
    lv_tableName VARCHAR2(10) := 'MyTable';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('OPTIONS(SKIP=1)');
    dbms_output.put_line('LOAD DATA');
    dbms_output.put_line('APPEND');
    dbms_output.put_line('INTO TABLE ' || lv_tableName);
    dbms_output.put_line('FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","');
    dbms_output.put_line('TRAILING NULLCOLS');
    dbms_output.put_line('(');
    ...
END;
/
```

Or don't use PL/SQL at all, of course:

```
SELECT 'OPTIONS(SKIP=1)' || CHR(10)
        || 'LOAD DATA' || CHR(10)
        || 'APPEND' || CHR(10)
        || 'INTO TABLE ' || lv_tableName || CHR(10)
        || 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","' || CHR(10)
        || 'TRAILING NULLCOLS' || CHR(10)
        || '(' || CHR(10)
  FROM DUAL
        ;
```

If the size is an issue, you can make it a CLOB:

```
SELECT to_clob('OPTIONS(SKIP=1)') || CHR(10)
...
```